# What is the need of separate address structure in sockaddr_in?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, ipv4

This is the internet(IPv4) socket address structure defined in **netinet/in.h**

```
struct sockaddr_in {
  uint8_t         sin_len;      
  sa_family_t     sin_family;   
  in_port_t       sin_port;                               
  struct in_addr  sin_addr;                                   
  char            sin_zero[8];  
};
struct in_addr {
  in_addr_t   s_addr;                                          
};
```

Here what is the need of separate structure only for address field.

Why can't we use following structure ?

```
  struct sockaddr_in {
  uint8_t         sin_len;      
  sa_family_t     sin_family;   
  in_port_t       sin_port;                               
  in_addr_t       sin_addr;                                   
  char            sin_zero[8];  
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's for historical reasons. In the early days of socket programming, `struct in_addr` contained a `union` of various structures so you could get to the individual bytes. This `union` became unnecessary when subnetting and classless addressing came along, but switching out the `struct` for a simple `unsigned long` would break a lot of code, so it just stayed that way.

If you're interested in network programming and you haven't yet picked up a copy of [UNIX Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013490012X) then I'd highly recommend doing so, it's a goldmine for little details like this.

Comment: Paul- Thanks for the reference book +1